# Position of "still"

Tags: differences, adverbs

I wonder which once is correct:

> He might **still** be waiting for you.

or

> He might be **still** waiting for you.

Do they mean the same?

Comment: Both are correct, and they have similar meaning, but the latter sounds a bit awkward to my ear.  "He might be waiting for you still" is also correct; it sounds better to me, but that formulation is uncommon in American English.  "He might still be [...]" is the formulation I most often hear.

Answer (score -2):

The phrase, "He might still be waiting for you," implies that he has been and is currently waiting.

The phrase, "He might be still waiting for you," implies that he has been waiting and the speaker is unsure of his current action.

Comment: I don't see how you can conclude that the first phrasing implies any assurance about current actions.  *Might* carries the aspect of doubt.  Don't both of these mean *He might be waiting for you still, or he might not*?  The only alternative that I can see is that the second sentence means that he might be unmoving while he waits.